# How to use maximum bandwith when uploading file from javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I try to upload chunked file from JavaScript using XMLHttpRequest to Aps.net MVC application, where 5MB size of each chunk. First tried to upload sequentially each chunk (after completing one chunk the take another one).
[Sequntial Upload image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnJrh.png)

Where each part to upload take 5 to 7 seconds.

Then I changed sequentially upload to parallel (sending 3 chunks at a time) but it's taken around 16 to 19 second.
[Parallel upload image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEsN2.png)

Where 3 chunks start same time, but end almost the same time, but it's same as Sequntial * 3 time.

server Side Code:

```
 [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class FileManagerController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// this method used to upload part file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadPartFile()
    {
        var temppath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp");

        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {

                string FileName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Headers["X-FILE-NAME"]);
                string ContentRange = Request.Headers["Content-Range"];
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(temppath, FileName), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    Request.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            });



        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

        }
        return Json(temppath, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

JavaScript Code:

var upload_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var prev_Loaded = 0;
                chunk = self.file[self.slice_method](chunk_part.range_start, chunk_part.range_end);

```
            upload_request.open('POST', self.options.url), true);
            upload_request.overrideMimeType('application/octet-stream');
            partFileName = self.uid + "_" + self.file.name + ".part_" + chunk_part.part_index;
            upload_request.setRequestHeader('X-FILE-NAME', encodeURIComponent(partFileName));

            upload_request.send(chunk);
```

How can i improve file upload speed?